# Node.js: What is the proper way of splitting code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, project-structure

My index.js file has a lot of code which could be split into many pieces.

Basically it looks something like this:

```
importing many dependencies;
importing many custom functions;

defining constants;

setting up express;
setting up apollo-server;

post-request #1
get-request #1
requests....

app.listern on port
```

I want my `index.js` file to contain **only imports**

To do so I've split my code into many .js files. The majority of files doesn't export anything, but represented as a piece of code like my this:

```
// it's a listen.js file
db.sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
});
```

I import it like this using es6 syntax (I import the whole file):

```
import './core/api/rest/listen'
```

and get an error:

```
db is not defined
```

I understand why it's not defined in `listen.js`, because I did not imported it into `listen.js`, but I imported `db` in my `index.js` before I importing `listen.js`. Why doesn't it visible?

BTW, `db` here is just one of many variables that raises an error.

**Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that if I import all my variables/constants/dependencies in index.js all these variables become accessible to imported files**

Comment: are you using babel in node.js? because node.js not support import yet... if not please use require.

Comment: @Ofear Yes, I do use it, I guess using `require` would not be an answer to my question

Comment: And where are you declaring on db? I don't see any declaration of variable named db

Comment: @Ofear, it's declared in a separate file and exported as a constant. It's imported before I import `listen.js`

Comment: try using `import {*} from './core/api/rest/listen'` <- this is not the best practice to use *.... btw.. are you exporting all those variables? can we see a glimpse of this file? `./core/api/rest/listen`

Comment: My editor treats this as an error. Maybe it's because I do not have any exports in (for instance) `listen.js`

Comment: Can you post part of listen.js?

Comment: @Ofear, I've already done this. My `listen.js` only has 2 lines of code and `db` is not imported into `listen.js` directly. But it's imported in `index.js` before  `listen.js`

Comment: The import statement is used to import bindings which are **exported** by another module.
Please see more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

You need to export the things you want to import

Comment: Wow.. how could I have missed this.... Thank you)

Comment: Hi @John Award, If this is the right answer please accept it and let others that have the same issues to understand the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **import** statement is used to import bindings which are **exported** by another module.

Please see more: [developer.mozilla.org/.../Statements/import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

You need to export the class/ functions/ variables you want to import